# How to remove unwanted whitespace css/html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have implemented BOOTSTRAP 3, NAV TABS to display content. But it takes the height of longest tabs, and white space is seen in other tabs. Why is this happening? I tried everything, but it didn't work.

The Link is: http://n.lookten.com/merchants.html

Can anyone suggest me whats happening here?

Thank You.

Comment: Can you post some code or a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css-

```
section.slice.bg-6{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a difference of 1px.

Modify this class as

```
//bootstrap.min.css line no. 7
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```